# How to create a VM with multiple NICs with Terraform on Openstack

Tags: openstack, terraform

I try to use Terraform to deploy some machines on an Openstack Cloud.

I have no problem to create networks, subnet, keys, security groups and rules, floating ip, network ports (with security groups attached), but, when I try to create compute instances with two NICs (network ports created before), I have a syntax error with no hint to resolve it.

Could you help me please ?

My code is:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "RNGPR-REBOND-01" {
  name            = "RNGPR-REBOND-01"
  flavor_name     = "${var.MyFlavor}"
  image_id        = "${var.MyImage}"
  key_pair        = "${var.CODOB}-keypair"
  network {
    port = "${openstack_networking_port_v2.RNGPR-REBOND-01-eth0.id}"
    access_network = true
  }
  network {
    port = "${openstack_networking_port_v2.RNGPR-REBOND-01-eth1.id}"
  }
  floating_ip = "${openstack_compute_floatingip_v2.FloatingIp-RNGPR-REBOND-01.address}"
}

resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "RNGPR-LB-01" {
  name            = "RNGPR-LB-01"
  flavor_name     = "${var.MyFlavor}"
  image_id        = "${var.MyImage}"
  key_pair        = "${var.CODOB}-keypair"
  network {
    port = "${openstack_networking_port_v2.RNGPR-LB-01-eth0.id}"
  }
  network {
    port = "${openstack_networking_port_v2.RNGPR-LB-01-eth1.id}"
  }
  floating_ip = "${openstack_compute_floatingip_v2.FloatingIp-RNGPR-LB-01.address}"
}
```

And the syntax error is:

```
Error applying plan:
2 error(s) occurred:
* openstack_compute_instance_v2.RNGPR-REBOND-01: Error creating OpenStack server: Invalid request due to incorrect syntax or missing required parameters.
* openstack_compute_instance_v2.RNGPR-LB-01: Error creating OpenStack server: Invalid request due to incorrect syntax or missing required parameters.
```

.

Comment: I found my mistake: I declared keypairs as name = "${var.CODOB} and I tried to use it form my instances as name = "${var.CODOB}-keypair.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, these error messages aren't very helpful.

I would first set **TF_LOG=DEBUG** and **OS_DEBUG=1** wherever you are running terraform. This will print error messages that are actually beneficial.

One time I was trying to create a server with a key pair that my user didn't have access to in openstack. I was receiving the same error and didn't figure it out until Debugging was set.

Answer (score 0):

From terraform documentation you need to specify the network name or id in this case.

Importing instance with multiple network interfaces.
Nova returns the network interfaces grouped by network, thus not in creation order. That means that if you have multiple network interfaces you must take care of the order of networks in your configuration.

As example we want to import an instance with one ephemeral root disk, and 3 network interfaces.

```
Examples

resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "boot-from-volume" {
  name            = "boot-from-volume"
  flavor_id       = "<flavor_id"
  key_pair        = "<keyname>"
  image_id        = "<image_id>"
  security_groups = ["default"]

  network {
    name = "<network1>"
  }
  network {
    name = "<network2>"
  }
  network {
    name = "<network1>"
    fixed_ip_v4 = "<fixed_ip_v4>"
  }

}
```

In the above configuration the networks are out of order compared to what nova and thus the import code returns, which means the plan will not be empty after import.